# MySQL: Disable logging for table updates/inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, mariadb

Is there a way to disable logging of updates/inserts to a **particular table** in MySQL/MariaDB?

---

In our database we have multiple tables and we would like to disable the logging of INSERT and UPDATE events for a specific table only.  `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;` and `SET GLOBAL general_log = 0;` provide a pretty coarse level control over logging.  We are looking for much finer-grained control over logging.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the general_log? The general log a rather course way of achieving anything and really should only be enabled for short periods. Which Mysql/MariaDB version? With an objective defined maybe there's other mechanism that can help.

Comment: @danblack Our MySQL version is somewhat dated (`5.6.47`). Most of our tables, except one, do not get updated all that frequently, so we would like to track updates and inserts to those tables.  One of our tables gets updated very frequently, so we would like to disable logging for that table **alone**.

Answer (score 1):

Use binary logging and put the particular table in its own database with [binlog-ignore-db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-ignore-db) set for that database.